# xamarin mvvmcross 5 c# fragment ensurebindingcontextset dialog

Tags: xamarin, binding, dialog, fragment, mvvmcross

For MVVMCROSS 5.7.0, there is an error in my project:`MvxDialogFragment<EventResendDialogViewModel>` does not contain a definition for `EnsureBindingContextSet` in `public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)`.

`EnsureBindingContextSet` is removed in MVVMCROSS 5.7.0 but I can't find any alternative or old implementation of this. Any suggestions are welcome!

`MvxDialogFragment` is from `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method was removed in this [Pull request](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/2280) because the only thing it did was to call an extension method.

So just use  the [extension method](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/5.7.0/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment/MvxFragmentExtensions.cs#L83) in `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4.MvxFragmentExtensions` to do that:

```cs
this.EnsureBindingContextIsSet();
```

HIH